# How to bind JavaScript based date column in Snowflake SQL

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am creating snowflake JavaScript based store procedure. How can i refer the date data type variable in snowflake sql.

Here is the sample code:
In the below code ,please suggest how can i use 'dnblatestdt' variable in sql statement.

```
create  or replace procedure test_proc_registration_master_perished_dt(PARAM_REG_SUB_UUID VARCHAR)
returns varchar not null
language javascript
as
$$
     
  /*get latest ingestion_uuid for the given state*/
  var step01=`select distinct dnb_applicable_dt,ingestion_uuid from temp_registration_hash_master `;
  var statement01=snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: step01,binds: [PARAM_REG_SUB_UUID]} );
  variable1= statement01.execute();
  variable1.next();
  dnblatestdt=variable1.getColumnValue(1);
  ingsuuid=variable1.getColumnValue(2);
       
  /* check if the ingestion is successful or not*/
  var step02=`select INGESTION_SUCCESSFUL  from FILE_INGESTION_HISTORY where  ingestion_uuid=:1 and date=:2::TIMESTAMP_LTZ::DATE`;
  var statement02=snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: step02,binds: [ingsuuid,dnblatestdt]} );
  variable2= statement02.execute();
  variable2.next();
  ingsindc=variable2.getColumnValue(1);

  return 'success'
$$
```

Comment: What data type is **dnb_applicable_dt**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wrote a much simpler function that uses a similar pattern to your code:

```
create  or replace procedure test_proc()
returns varchar not null
language javascript
as
$$
     
  var step01 = `SELECT 6::number, '2022-01-27'::timestamp_ntz;`;
  var statement01 = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: step01} );
  results1 = statement01.execute();
  results1.next();
  ingsuuid = results1.getColumnValue(1);
  dnblatestdt = results1.getColumnValue(2);
       
  /* check if the ingestion is successful or not*/
  var step02=`SELECT :1 * 2, DATEADD(year,-1, :2::timestamp_ntz);`;
  var statement02 = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: step02,binds: [ingsuuid , dnblatestdt]} );
  results2 = statement02.execute();
  results2.next();
  ingsindc = results2.getColumnValue(1);

  return 'success'
$$
;
```

and using it works for me:

```
call test_proc();


TEST_PROC
success
```

I swapped the order of the reading parameters on the first function, but that should not be a problem.

this makes me thing your casting on the second instance is not working

```
:2::TIMESTAMP_LTZ::DATE
```

so I would suggest moving that casting to the first function, which you can test outside the stored procedure, thus.

```
SELECT DISTINCT dnb_applicable_dt::TIMESTAMP_LTZ::DATE, ingestion_uuid 
FROM temp_registration_hash_master
```

when that is happy, you shouldn't need any casting on the second used of the values.